# R - "Unmelt" a melted dataframe back to original dimensions

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Consider the following data frame:

```
> df <- data.frame(x=sample(c(0,1),9,replace=T))
> df$x <- factor(df$x)
> df
  x
1 1
2 1
3 0
4 1
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 1
9 1
```

Let's say it came from a binary logistic regression output (0,1) and I want to transform it in a 3x3 raster. Before this, I need to have a 3x3 dataframe or an array. How can I reach this result:

```
df
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0
[3,]    0    1    1
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks @A. Webb for you comment. I haven't mentioned an additional task. I have a large data frame (994704 rows) that should me divided into 23 204x212 matrices or arrays (43248 rows each) according to another field (numeric), let's say "y", in order to be converted to rasters:

```
    > df
          y    x
        1 27   1
        2 27   1
        3 27   0
        4 27   1
        5 27   0
        6 27   0
        7 27   0
        8 27   1
        9 27   1
       10 27.5 1
       11 27.5 1
       12 27.5 0
       13 27.5 1
       14 27.5 0
       15 27.5 0
       16 27.5 0
       17 27.5 1
       18 27.5 1
        ...
   994704 38   1
```

My rationale, even I'm not sure how to implement it, is something like:

```
for (i in unique(df$y)){
  df.new.[i] <- raster(matrix(df$x[each 43248 rows],204,212,byrow=T))
}
```

So it should result in 23 rasters (204x212) named as df.new.[y value]. That's a more realistic example based on my challenge here.

Comment: `matrix(as.numeric(levels(df$x)[df$x]),3,3,byrow=TRUE)`?

Comment: @A.Webb, thanks for your comment. It works, indeed. But I've made an edit on my post in order to closely reflect my real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you have a numeric vector (do not turn it into a factor)

```
#dfx <- as.numeric(df$x)
dfx <- runif(994704)
```

Now you can do

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(nrow=204,ncol=212,nl=23)
values(b) <- dfx
```

`RasterBrick` 'b' is more handy than a list of `RasterLayer` objects; but if that is what you need:

```
bs <- unstack(b)
```

This assumes that the values are in the right order (raster by raster, row-wise from the left upper corner within rasters)

A subsetting approach that you envisioned would be something like

```
#example data
y <- rep(1:23, each=204*212)
df <- data.frame(x=dfx, y=y)
```

now do

```
r <- raster(nrow=204,ncol=212)
x <- list()
for (i in unique(df$y)) {
    v <- df[df$y==i, 'x']
    x[[i]] <- setValues(r, v)
}

s <- stack(x)
```